# Who is being "taken" in Matthew 24:40-41?

Tags: greek, matthew, eschatology

[Matthew 24:40-41](http://esv.to/Mt24.40-41) (ESV)

> Then two men will be in the field; one will be taken and one left. Two
>   women will be grinding oat at the mill; one will be taken and one left.

One of the interpretations I've read of these verses connects the people being "taken" in 40-41 to the (wicked) people whom the flood waters "took" in verse 39. The Greek for these words—παραλαμβάνεται and ἦρεν respectively—doesn't appear to me to have the same connection as in English, but I'm not well-versed enough to be certain. Would these words have been understood similarly in Greek? In 40-41, are the wicked being "taken" or "left behind" (ἀφίεται)?

Comment: Similar questions: [Meaning of “Where there is a dead body, there the vultures will gather.”](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13/meaning-of-where-there-is-a-dead-body-there-the-vultures-will-gather) and [Where is the dead body in Luke 17?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3176/where-is-the-dead-body-in-luke-17) over at Christianity SE.

Comment: Was going to ask a *truly* similar question but was then informed of your own. I have (at least) commented below, underneath what I believe to be the most accurate answer, whether that person gets the message, or not ..... You now have a 13th vote, which you should not obviously perceive as a negative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NET Bible has a helpful [comment](http://classic.net.bible.org/bible.php?book=Mat&chapter=24#n58):

> There is debate among commentators and scholars over the phrase *one will be taken* and *one left* about whether one is taken for judgment or for salvation. If the imagery is patterned after the rescue of Noah from the flood, as some suggest, the ones taken are the saved (as Noah was) and those left behind are judged. The imagery, however, is not directly tied to the identification of the two groups. Its primary purpose in context is to picture the sudden, surprising separation of the righteous and the judged (i.e., condemned) at the return of the Son of Man. [missing spaces inserted]

There's an excellent chance that Matthew had the text of Mark at hand when he composed this section.  [Mark 13:32](http://www.esvbible.org/Mark+13/) strongly parallels [Matthew 24:36](http://www.esvbible.org/Matthew+24/).  But Mark doesn't include the sayings about Noah or the one taken and one left.  On the other hand, the sayings are in Luke 17:26-37 ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/search/Luke%2017/)):

> Just as it was in the days of Noah, so will it be in the days of the Son of Man. They were eating and drinking and marrying and being given in marriage, until the day when Noah entered the ark, and the flood came and destroyed them all. Likewise, just as it was in the days of Lot—they were eating and drinking, buying and selling, planting and building, but on the day when Lot went out from Sodom, fire and sulfur rained from heaven and destroyed them all—so will it be on the day when the Son of Man is revealed. On that day, let the one who is on the housetop, with his goods in the house, not come down to take them away, and likewise let the one who is in the field not turn back. Remember Lot's wife. Whoever seeks to preserve his life will lose it, but whoever loses his life will keep it. I tell you, in that night there will be two in one bed. One will be taken and the other left. There will be two women grinding together. One will be taken and the other left.” And they said to him, “Where, Lord?” He said to them, “Where the corpse is, there the vultures will gather.”

By adding the story of Lot fleeing from Sodom, Luke emphasizes the concept of the one leaving the scene being righteous and the one who stays (or even looks back) being wicked.  Further, Luke talks about the wicked being "destroyed" rather than being "took".  (I don't know what to make of the vultures gathering, however.  Perhaps that could be a separate question.)

The usual theory for passages included in both Luke and Matthew, but not Mark, is the *Q* hypothesis.  The story of Noah and the one taken and one left are usually assigned to *Q*.  (See [*New Testament History: A Narrative Account*](http://books.google.com/books/about/New_Testament_history.html?id=IVIRAQAAIAAJ) by Ben Witherington III for instance.)  Therefore, these sayings were written down quite early and it's possible they were the basis for a passage in one of Paul's earliest letters, 1 Thessalonians 4:13-18 ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/1+Thessalonians+4/)):

> But we do not want you to be uninformed, brothers, about those who are asleep, that you may not grieve as others do who have no hope. For since we believe that Jesus died and rose again, even so, through Jesus, God will bring with him those who have fallen asleep. For this we declare to you by a word from the Lord, that we who are alive, who are left until the coming of the Lord, will not precede those who have fallen asleep. For the Lord himself will descend from heaven with a cry of command, with the voice of an archangel, and with the sound of the trumpet of God. And the dead in Christ will rise first. Then we who are alive, who are left, will be caught up together with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air, and so we will always be with the Lord. Therefore encourage one another with these words.

Unfortunately, this is a controversial text, but if Paul has in mind Matthew 24 his interpretation is clear.  He is looking to a future coming of the Lord and notes that some of the the Thessalonians are concerned that the brothers and sisters who are dead will be among those who are left and thus counted as wicked.  Paul counters, using language from the Jewish and early-Christian resurrection hope, that the dead and the living will be reunited in the coming of the Lord.  Both will be taken if they are counted among the righteous.  (I think Paul is subtly shifting terms by saying those who are alive are "left".  The dead have already been taken to await the future resurrection.  But it's not completely clear.)

Finally, while many translations use the "took" language in verse 39, some (ESV, NLT, MSG, and NRSV) use the verb "swept".  When you think about it, the people who were "taken" were really the ones in the ark who were lifted away from the earth, while the ones who were pulled into the water were left behind to their fate.  As you mention, the connection between the wicked and the taken turns mostly on the English translation rather than directly in the Greek.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know enough Greek to say definitively one way or the other, but the idea that those who are "taken" are like those who were "swept away" makes more sense than the opposite.

It may also be relevant that in the parable of the wheat and the weeds, ([Matthew 13:24-30](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nrs/matthew/passage.aspx?q=matthew+13:24-30)), the weeds sown by an enemy are the first to be "taken" at harvest time.

> He put before them another parable: "The kingdom of heaven may be compared to someone who sowed good seed in his field; but while everybody was asleep, an enemy came and sowed weeds among the wheat, and then went away. So when the plants came up and bore grain, then the weeds appeared as well. And the slaves of the householder came and said to him, "Master, did you not sow good seed in your field? Where, then, did these weeds come from?' He answered, "An enemy has done this.' The slaves said to him, "Then do you want us to go and gather them?' But he replied, "No; for in gathering the weeds you would uproot the wheat along with them. Let both of them grow together until the harvest; and at harvest time I will tell the reapers, Collect the weeds first and bind them in bundles to be burned, but gather the wheat into my barn.' "

Comment: Excellent parallel.  That's a far simpler (and therefore better) answer than my own. ;-)

Comment: Secret Rapture people wouldn't be too happy with this answer :P I've always read it more like @JonEricson connecting the same word Paul uses in Thessalonians. But I don't think any specific doctrine, one way or the other,  should be taken from it as many try.

Comment: The logical order seems to be: 
1.  Gather together the weeds into bundles.
2. Gather the wheat into the barn. 
3. Burn the weeds. To burn the weeds before gathering the wheat into the barn would  jeopardize the wheat. It must therefore be taken away first.

Comment: @Constantthin I grew up on a farm and have actually pulled weeds from a wheat field. The weeds have to be taken away first. If you don't physically remove the weeds from the field, their seeds will get mixed in with the grain at harvest time. Then you'd be planting weeds with the wheat the next year. Burning the weeds could happen before or after harvest, because it's not done in the field.

Comment: Interesting to speak with somebody with  experience. Are you saying that the normal procedure is to remove the weeds well before harvest time, rather than at harvest time?

Comment: @Constantthin Generally, yes. The weeds can be pulled at any time after the plants are big enough to tell the difference between weeds and wheat. But pull them too early, and you're likely to have more weeds to pull later. Pull them too late, though, and you might have trouble getting through the field, since every plant fills more space as it grows. Another problem, if you wait until the wheat is ripe, is the grain can fall off if the plant is disturbed. So normally the weeds are gone before the wheat is fully ripe.

Comment: Although, with modern farming equipment, pulling weeds is not as necessary unless you're planning to replant the grain the next year.

Comment: So there is a normal amount of weeds growing in a wheat field year by year. But what about somebody (an enemy) purposely worsen the situation by walking through the field scattering massive amounts of weed seeds. Would that change the timing of cleansing the field from weeds?

Comment: @Constantthin If anything, intentional sabotage like that would normally necessitate starting earlier in order to get all the weeds. That's why, in the parable, the workers ask if they should start pulling weeds immediately. But since the weeds represent living human beings, the master wants to wait, to give them extra time to repent. But he can't wait forever. The weeds have to be pulled before the harvest can begin.

Comment: I suppose that the big question is if the wheat field represents the world or the church? If the world then the story starts at the beginning of history, which is either the garden of eden or the flood. Otherwise if it is the church it would start sometime after the dispersal of the believers from Jerusalem.

Answer (score 2):

The differences in the Greek from verse 39 to verse 40 are interesting. But it seems that the references and pictures Jesus gives to support what he is saying would make the ones who are taken the wicked.

> Matthew 24:36-44 ESV “But concerning that day and hour no one knows, not even the angels of heaven, nor the Son, but the Father only. 37 For as were the days of Noah, so will be the coming of the Son of Man. 38 For as in those days before the flood they were eating and drinking, marrying and giving in marriage, until the day when Noah entered the ark, 39 and they were unaware until the flood came and swept them all away, so will be the coming of the Son of Man. 40 Then two men will be in the field; one will be taken and one left. 41 Two women will be grinding at the mill; one will be taken and one left. 42 Therefore, stay awake, for you do not know on what day your Lord is coming. 43 But know this, that if the master of the house had known in what part of the night the thief was coming, he would have stayed awake and would not have let his house be broken into. 44 Therefore you also must be ready, for the Son of Man is coming at an hour you do not expect

In verse 38 he says that "they were eating, and drinking, marrying and giving in marriage" speaking of the wicked.  In verse 39 he says that "they were unaware until the flood came and swept them away." Again speaking of the wicked. The context is on those who were "swept" or "taken" away. He then says this is the same thing that will happen when he returns.  The wicked will be taken and the righteous left.  It wouldn't make sense to all of a sudden reverse the context from speaking about in the days of Noah and the wicked being swept or taken away and then say that when he returns the opposite would happen.  If that were the case then he would have said the coming of the Son of Man will be the opposite of the days of Noah.

Also, in connection to what he is saying in verse 43 and 44 he refers to himself as a thief.  A thief does not steal what is his.  A thief steals what is not his.  It seems he is telling his disciples to be ready and watchful over themselves so that they remain his and do not suffer loss in that day that he returns.

The passage in Luke 17:37 gives us the answer.

> And they said to him, “Where, Lord?” He said to them, “Where the corpse is, there the vultures will gather.”

Again the context to the return of Jesus is in the days of Noah, where judgment swept over the earth.  Also in the day of Lot, when Sodom and Gomorrah were judged.  The context is clearly judgement and that many people lost their lives.  When they asked for clarity on where the one was taken, he clarify's that it's not a place that they are taken too, it's that their lives are taken.

This also lines up with Old Testament prophecies of what will happen when the Messiah appears.

> Isaiah 66:15-16 “For behold, the Lord will come in fire, 
>   and his chariots like the whirlwind, 
>   to render his anger in fury, 
>   and his rebuke with flames of fire. 
>   16For by fire will the Lord enter into judgment, 
>   and by his sword, with all flesh; 
>   and those slain by the Lord shall be many.

Also in Revelation, the return of Jesus is described the same way

> Revelation 19:11-18 Then I saw heaven opened, and behold, a white horse! The one sitting on it is called Faithful and True, and in righteousness he judges and makes war. 12 His eyes are like a flame of fire, and on his head are many diadems, and he has a name written that no one knows but himself. 13 He is clothed in a robe dipped in blood, and the name by which he is called is The Word of God. 14And the armies of heaven, arrayed in fine linen, white and pure, were following him on white horses. 15 From his mouth comes a sharp sword with which to strike down the nations, and he will rule them with a rod of iron. He will tread the winepress of the fury of the wrath of God the Almighty. 16 On his robe and on his thigh he has a name written, King of kings and Lord of lords. 17 Then I saw an angel standing in the sun, and with a loud voice he called to all the birds that fly directly overhead, “Come, gather for the great supper of God, 18 to eat the flesh of kings, the flesh of captains, the flesh of mighty men, the flesh of horses and their riders, and the flesh of all men, both free and slave, both small and great.”

**Final Thought**

It's important to see that Jesus is not giving a detailed description of what the end of the age will look like.  He is giving a summary of highlights.  When taken with other "end of the age" scriptures from both the Old Testament and the New Testament we get a clearer picture.  But I must say that we won't understand it all until after it's over.  Much like the disciples during Jesus' first coming.  They understood vaguely what Jesus was saying about his death, burial, and resurrection.  It didn't come together for them until after it all happened. The reality is that it doesn't matter how much someone tells you about something you've never seen, it's not crystal clear until you actually witness it for yourself.

Comment: Great answer +1

Comment: This answer is right on the money (and not just this answer) and worthy of an upvote. However, it would seem that you are not all that interested in what others on this site might have to say, whether it be with regard to this Q, or any other, so I see little point in rewarding. I would suggest that you *interact* more and show some *real* interest, otherwise you risk being perceived as nothing but *arrogant*.

Answer (score 1):

The subject can be found in verses 4 and 5 of Matt. 24.

The first one taken is taken into deception and worship the antichrist. The one left is left waiting for the true Christ to return.
The anti christ comes first PEACEFULLY AND PROSPEROUSLY. He comes claiming to be christ, the whole world will whore after Him thinking he's here to "Rapture" them away...

Read of the coming anti christ in these chapters ...as well as many others.

- Mark- 13
- Math -24
- 2 Thess- 2

Comment: Matthew 24:4-5: "And Jesus answered and said unto them, Take heed that no man deceive you. For many shall come in my name, saying, I am Christ; and shall deceive many." Could you expand on your answer a little, to help us understand how this passage tells us the identities of those who will be taken and left?

Comment: No, this is wrong. So, one is in bed, one gets up to follow the anti-Christ, and the other stays in bed? The idea is they are sleeping, perhaps husband and wife, and one is taken away "like the flood".  It also says "It will be just like this on the day the *Son of Man is revealed*." just before he says all that, so this already sets up the return of Christ.

Answer (score 1):

The reference to "one shall be taken and one left" is a reference to Zechariah's prediction that half of the people of Jerusalem would be taken away from Jerusalem as captives:

> [Zec 14:1-2 KJV] 1 Behold, the day of the LORD cometh, and thy spoil shall be divided in the midst of thee. 2 For I will gather all nations against Jerusalem to battle; and the city shall be taken, and the houses rifled, and the women ravished; and **half of the city shall go forth into captivity, and the residue of the people shall not be cut off from the city**.

So what does it mean that "the residue of the people shall not be cut off from the city"? Perhaps it means that the ones taken will be disenfranchised, their goods confiscated and their rights terminated as a ["felony"](https://books.google.com/books?id=DyheAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA589&ots=7hrodIm1Bz&dq=second%20temple%20roman%20felonia&pg=PA589#v=onepage&q=second%20temple%20roman%20felonia&f=false). If so this might help explain the 1.1 million non-combatants killed in the judgment that fell around 70ad and why Revelation refers to the Jews hiding in the rocks of the hills, wishing that they had died in the war.

The birds come to pluck out their eyes as they eat their carcasses:

> [Isa 5:25 NKJV] 25 Therefore the anger of the LORD is aroused against His people; He has stretched out His hand against them And stricken them, And the hills trembled. Their carcasses [were] as refuse in the midst of the streets. For all this His anger is not turned away, But His hand [is] stretched out still.
>
> [Jer 9:22 NKJV] 22 Speak, "Thus says the LORD: 'Even the carcasses of men shall fall as refuse on the open field, Like cuttings after the harvester, And no one shall gather [them].' "
>
> [Jer 16:18 NKJV] 18 "And first I will repay double for their iniquity and their sin, because they have defiled My land; they have filled My inheritance with the carcasses of their detestable and abominable idols."

It doesn't matter if it is a raven or an eagle!:

> [Pro 30:17 KJV] 17 The eye [that] mocketh at [his] father, and despiseth to obey [his] mother, the ravens of the valley shall pick it out, and the young eagles shall eat it.

Answer (score -1):

Matthew 23-25 concerns the condemnation, judgment and reward of the Old Covenant people. The context of Matthew 24 is thus the persecution of the first century church, the Roman siege and the complete destruction of the Temple and city, "the days of vengeance," the curse upon the Land predicted by Malachi and reiterated by John. The entire prophecy was fulfilled.

Those "taken" are taken in judgment during the time of God's wrath upon Jerusalem and Judaea, which would be no respecter of persons. The end would come "with a flood" of troops (Dan 9:26; see also Isaiah 8:8 concerning an Assyrian "flood" submerging Judah "up to the neck").

It is also very helpful to read all Jesus' parables in this first century light. We can certainly make applications, but their purpose was to warn the Jews of the imminent end of the Old Covenant. It was Herod's Temple that was built upon sand.

Matthew 10:23 When you are persecuted in one place, flee to another. Truly I tell you, you will not finish going through the towns of Israel before the Son of Man comes.

Matthew 23:36 Truly I tell you, all this will come on this generation.

Matthew 24:34 Truly I tell you, this generation will certainly not pass away until all these things have happened.

Answer (score -3):

> Those who see clearly, (male) are working in the field.

then they are NOT the church, because the church is always 'she'

Actually [in Luke 17] it's at night and two are in bed, no gender specified,  and two women grinding, going about life as usual working, sleeping, remember all of the virgins are asleep when the bridegroom finally comes.

> Matt 25:1“At that time the kingdom of heaven will be like ten virgins
>   who took their lamps and went out to meet the bridegroom. 2Five of
>   them were foolish and five were wise. 3The foolish ones took their
>   lamps but did not take any oil with them. 4The wise ones, however,
>   took oil in jars along with their lamps. 5The bridegroom was a long
>   time in coming, and they all became drowsy and fell asleep.

will we be so wrapped up in living we won't see the season of His 'visitation'?  we can't know the day or hour, but we can know the season.

Comment: Hi Mark and welcome to _[hermeneutics.SE]_.  This really isn't the sort of [answer we are looking for](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/533/68).  In particular, I don't follow the jump: `then they are NOT the church, because the church is always 'she'`.  It seems like you are leaving out some of the steps...

Answer (score -4):

In sensus plenior, when there are two things, they are two aspects of the same thing. This is derived from the meaning of 'vav' as 'and', which both joins and separates two objects to clarify their commonality and differences.

Two men in the field are one man who has a spirit and flesh (two parts). His spirit is taken to immediately be in the presence of the Lord, and his body is left behind (dead).

Two women grinding oat at the mill are one woman. Her spirit is taken while her body is left behind.

Rather than being redundant sayings, as is the case with futuristic interpretations of eschatology, the sayings are notably different.

Determining the usage of 'male' and 'female' as metaphor:

1. Christ is male, the bride is female. Paul says that marriage represents Christ and the church (the bride). [1]
2. The male understands, the female does not understand [2]

Grinding, boiling, thrashing, etc. are all metaphor for judgement.

Those who see clearly, (male) are working in the field. They are harvesting in God's field. Those who do not see clearly (female) are grinding oats. They are those who are not 'understanding'.
Both die in this world and have body separated from Spirit and go immediately to the presence of the Lord.

1. Eph 5:32 This is a great mystery: but I speak concerning Christ and the church.
2. 1Co 14:35 And if they will learn any thing, let them ask their husbands at home: for it is a shame for women to speak in the church.