# Who are the two witnessesof Rev 11:3?

Tags: second-coming

Who are the two witnesses of Rev 11:3?

"And I will give power to my two witnesses and they will prophesy one thousand two hundred and sixty days , clothed in sackcloth. These are the two olive trees and the two lampstands standing before the God of the earth." Rev 3:3,4

I suggest they are the resurrected Zerubbabel (line of David) and Joshua (high priest).

"Speak to Zerubbabel, governor of Judah, I will shake heaven and earth ..."
Haggai 2:21

"In that day says the LORD of Hosts, 'I will take you, Zerubbabel My Servant, the son of Shealtiel,' says the LORD, 'and will make you like a signet ring, for I have chosen you,' says the LORD of hosts." (given authority) Haggai 2:23

"This is the word of the LORD to Zerubbabel: 'Not by might nor by power, but by My Spirit,' says the LORD of hosts. Who are you O great mountain? Before Zerubabbel you shall become a plain! And he shall bring forth the capstone." (temple mount prep)
Zech 4:6,7

"The hands of Zerubbabel Have laid the foundation of this temple; His hands shall also finish it." Zech 4:9

"Now Joshua was clothed with filthy garments, and was standing before the angel." Zech 3:3 "...And to him He said, 'See I have removed your iniquity from you ...'" Zech 3:4b

"These are the two anointed ones, who stand beside the Lord of the whole earth." zech 4:14

Comment: As currently worded, this is not a question but an answer.  I suggest you close this question and then provide this material as an answer to the referenced question at https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/who-what-are-the-two-witnesses-in-revelation-11

Comment: Bagpipes - interesting but the comments didn't have an answer to my specific question.

Comment: Interesting but I didn't see an answer to my specific question i.e., resurrected Zerubbabel and Josuah. Yes or No.

Comment: Dottard  - I took your advice and posted to 1603, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The two witnesses in Revelation 11 are a symbolic representation of God's people throughout time. They are the " two olive branches ( olive trees, Rev. 11:4) , which through the two golden pipes empty the golden oil out of themselves "( Zech 4:12).
They represent the Old and New covenant " church ", bringing the  " oil of gladness" ( Psalm 45:7) or the " golden oil" of the  gospel to the whole world.
The " two witnesses " are the " two anointed ones , that stand by the Lord of the whole earth" ( Zech. 4: 14).

During the time of their prophecy,  the " fire" of the  judgment of God's word "proceedeth out of their mouth" (Rev. 11:5). (Remember , the Bible, especially in the book of Revelation,  is highly allegorical.  Unless you want to  believe that two people will be walking around incinerating people with fire from their mouths?). Although I do not completely understand the withholding of rain or turning waters to blood( v.6), I certainly believe it has to do with preaching the gospel.
The soon to come period of great tribulation begins when the testimony of the true believers is finished ( v.7), as they ( we?) are overcome and " spiritually" killed (v. 7)  by the flood of false gospels that mark the true nature of the tribulation..... " For there shall arise false Christs, and false prophets, and shall shew great signs and wonders; insomuch that, if it were possible, they shall deceive the very elect" ( Mt. 24:24).
The Bible was not written in a way where everyone will understand it, especially regarding end time prophecy.  In other words I seriously doubt there will be a " two witnesses  tracker app" that the world can download.

Comment: Walter - I think you're saying you don't agree with my suggestion that the resurrected Zerubbabel and Joshua are the two witnesses.

Comment: Sorry. I do not agree. Nor do I agree with them being Moses and Elijah. I really do not believe that God will be sending anyone as a sign of what is to come. God's people will be guided by the Holy Spirit and the faith of Christ,  not by signs or appearances of old saints. This is an unfolding mystery. Do you think God is going to have everything laid out for the unsaved to understand ? The day of the Lord will come as a "thief in the night" for them. How is watching Moses or Joshua walking around projecting fire from their mouths " thief- like"? Watch out for "signs and lying wonders"!

Answer (score 0):

That is a great question..
I cannot say for sure, I can only share with you what I have searched and learned so far.
There's some that say they could be Moses and Enoch. And some say they could be Moses and Elijah.

I encourage you to continue searching the Word and seek the Holy Spirits guidance.

Here's some of verses that leads me to think the two witnesses are Moses and Elijah .

Let's see what the Bible says about these two witnesses.
Revelation 11: 3-6 kjv
3 And I will give power unto my two witnesses, and they shall prophesy a thousand two hundred and threescore days, clothed in sackcloth.
4 These are the two olive trees, and the two candlesticks standing before the God of the earth.
5 And if any man will hurt them, fire proceedeth out of their mouth, and devoureth their enemies: and if any man will hurt them, he must in this manner be killed.
6 These have power to shut heaven, that it rain not in the days of their prophecy: and have power over waters to turn them to blood, and to smite the earth with all plagues, as often as they will.

The two will have

1. Fire proceedeth out of their mouth, and devoureth their enemies.
2. Have power to shut heaven, that it rain not.
3. Have power over waters to turn them to blood and to smite the earth with all plagues.

The Word tells us in 2 Kings 1:10
"And Elijah answered and said to the captain of fifty, If I be a man of God, then let fire come down from heaven, and consume thee and thy fifty. And there came down fire from heaven, and consumed him and his fifty.

And in James 5:17-18,
Elias was a man subject to like passions as we are, and he prayed earnestly that it might not rain: and it rained not on the earth by the space of three years and six months.
18 And he prayed again, and the heaven gave rain, and the earth brought forth her fruit.

Luke 9:54 "And when his disciples James and John saw this, they said, Lord, wilt thou that we command fire to come down from heaven, and consume them, even as Elias did?"

In Exodus 7:20  "And Moses and Aaron did so, as the Lord commanded; and he lifted up the rod, and smote the waters that were in the river, in the sight of Pharaoh, and in the sight of his servants; and all the waters that were in the river were turned to blood."

Exodus tells about plagues over Egypt by Moses.

Also, in Matthew 17  Moses and Elijah are the two that appear talking with Jesus.
17:1 "after six days Jesus taketh Peter, James, and John his brother, and bringeth them up into an high mountain apart,
2 And was transfigured before them: and his face did shine as the sun, and his raiment was white as the light.
3 And, behold, there appeared unto them Moses and Elias talking with him.
4 Then answered Peter, and said unto Jesus, Lord, it is good for us to be here: if thou wilt, let us make here three tabernacles; one for thee, and one for Moses, and one for Elias.

The books of Luke and Mark also give account to the event.

Luke 9:30 "And, behold, there talked with him two men, which were Moses and Elias:

Mark 9:4 "And there appeared unto them Elias with Moses: and they were talking with Jesus."

(Note that Elias as a boys' name is pronounced ee-LYE-us. It is of Greek and Hebrew origin, and the meaning of Elias is "Jehovah is God". Biblical name from the Greek form of Elijah.)

Zechariah 4
11Then answered I, and said unto him, What are these two olive trees upon the right side of the candlestick and upon the left side thereof?
12 And I answered again, and said unto him, What be these two olive branches which through the two golden pipes empty the golden oil out of themselves?
13 And he answered me and said, Knowest thou not what these be? And I said, No, my lord.
14 Then said he, These are the two anointed ones, that stand by the Lord of the whole earth.

Revelation 11:5-6
5 And if any man will hurt them, fire proceedeth out of their mouth, and devoureth their enemies: and if any man will hurt them, he must in this manner be killed.
6 These have power to shut heaven, that it rain not in the days of their prophecy: and have power over waters to turn them to blood, and to smite the earth with all plagues, as often as they will.

Elijah spoke and ceased to rain for three and a half years, exactly, the time the witnesses will be on earth prophesizing. “

Notice the length of time in both verses.
James 5:17  "three years and six months."

Revelation 11:3 "a thousand two hundred and
threescore days." = 1,260 days

1,260 days = Three and a half years = 42 months

The tribulation will last 7 years . 3.5 years + 3.5 years =7 years.
In the middle of the 7 years is when the antichrist sits himself in the temple of God and demands all to serve him.
The last 3.5 years of the tribulation , the 2 witnesses will show up on the scene,  prophesying three years and six months.

There's more verses that answers about Elijah being taken up. And Moses burial and body. And phopshey the disciples discussed in the new testament  about "Elias must come first"

I hope this helps.

Comment: Crystal - Thank you for your insightful comments. "The last 3.5 years of the tribulation , the 2 witnesses will show up on the scene, prophesying three years and six months." Comment- I suggest that Rev 11:1 "...'Rise and measure the temple of God, the altar and those who worship there." Rev 11:3 "And I will give power to  my two witnesses, and will prophesy one thousand two hundred and sixty days, clothed in sackcloth." The temple is rebuilt, then the two witnesses prophesy for 3 1/2 years for first half of the 7 year tribulation period.