# Translation of ἀετοί in Matthew 24:28

Tags: greek, matthew

I know that [another question focuses on the meaning of the phrase in which this word is used](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/13/423), but I am only interested in the translation of the word itself (most answers to [that question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/13/423) take the translation 'vultures' as a given).

The plural nominative noun ἀετοί (from ἀετός) in Matthew 24:28 is [translated](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024:28&version=ESV;AKJV) as 'vultures' by most modern translations. However, the KJV translated it literally as 'eagles' ([see also Luke 17:37](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2017:37&version=ESV;AKJV)). The lexical entry for the noun in BDAG (2000) is:

> **ἀετός, οῦ, ὁ** (since Hom., who, as do many after him, writes αἰετός early Attic [cp. Jos., Bell. 5, 48]; ins, pap, LXX; Test12Patr,
>   ParJer; ApcMos 33; Jos., Bell. 1, 650f, Ant. 17, 151; Tat. 10, 1f;
>   DELG s.v. αἰετός) ***eagle*** symbol of swiftness Rv 12:14 (s. Ezk
>   17:3, 7); cp. 4:7; 8:13 (s. Boll 37f; 113f—ἀ. πετόμενος as Job 9:26).
>   Eating carrion, in the proverb (cp. Job 39:30) ἐκεῖ (ἐπι)συναχθήσονται
>   οἱ ἀ. Mt 24:28; Lk 17:37 (where ***vulture*** is meant; Aristot., HA
>   9, 32, 592b, 1ff, and Pliny, Hist. Nat. 10, 3 also class the vulture
>   among the eagles; TManson, Sayings of Jesus ’54, 147, emphasizes the
>   swiftness of the coming of the Day of the Son of Man). Moses forbade
>   eating of its flesh B 10:1, 4 (Dt 14:12; Lev 11:13).—M-M.

It is interesting that the lexicon says "where vulture is meant", as if the text is incorrect.

[Davïd posted some additional lexicons to consider](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/9113/translation-of-in-matthew-2428#comment19420_9113). [From the LSJ](http://www.tlg.uci.edu/lsj/#eid=1874&context=lsj&action=from-search):

> **ἀετός,** Ep., Lyr., Ion., and early Att. **αἰετός** (v. fin.), οῦ, ὁ, eagle, as a bird of omen, αἰ. τελειότατον πετεηνῶν *Il.8.247*, cf.
>   *12.201, Od. 2.146* (cf. II): favourite of Zeus, ὅστε σοὶ αὐτῷ φίλτατος οἰωνῶν *Il. 24.310*, cf. *Pi.P.1.6*; Διὸς . . πτηνὸς κύων,
>   δαφοινὸς αἰ. *A.Pr.1022*, cf. *Ag.136*; ὁ σκηπτροβάμων αἰ., κύων Διός
>   *S.Fr.885:—prov.*, αἰετὸς ἐν ποτανοῖς *Pi.N.3.80*; αἰετὸς ἐν νεφέλαισι, of a thing quite out of reach, *Ar.Av.987*; ἀετὸν κάνθαρος
>   μαιεύσομαι (v. μαιεύομαι):—the diff. kinds are distinguished by
>   specific names, *Arist.HA618b18 sqq.*
>
> **2.**. *eagle as a standard*, of the
>   Persians, *X.Cyr.7.1.4*; of the Romans, *Plu.Mar.23*, etc.
>
> **3.**. the constellation *Aquila*,
>   *Arat.591, Ptol. Tetr. 27, etc.
>
> **II.** *omen*, *Theoc.26.31*.
>
> **III.** *eagle-ray, Myliobatis aquila*, *Arist. HA540b18*.
>
> **IV.** in Architecture, *gable, pediment* (from its resemblance to outspread wings, *Gal.18(1).519), Ar.Av. 1110, ubi v. Sch., IG1.322 ii
>   80, cf. Pi.O.13.21, Fr.53, E.Fr.764*; ὑπὸ τὸν αὐτὸν ἀετὸν ὑπελθεῖν
>   come under the same roof, *IG14.644* (Bruttii, iii B.C.).
>
> **V.** name of *bandage*, *Sor.Fasc.12.508C*.
>
> **VI.** *temporal vein* (Magna Graecia), Philistion *ap.Ruf.Onom.201*.
>
> **VII.** *iron part of spoke of wheel*, *Poll.1.145, Hsch*.
>
> **VIII.** Astrol. and Magic, fabulous plant growing in Libya, Pamphil. ap. *Gal.11.798, Cat.Cod.Astr.7.222*. (αἰετός in early Att. Inscrr.,
>   *IG1.322ii80, 2.1054.39*; αἰητός *Arat.522, v.l. in Pi.P.4.4;* αἰβετός (i.e. αἰϜετός) Hsch.) [ᾱ always.]

[The Moulton & Milligan lexical entry](https://archive.org/stream/vocabularyofgree00mouluoft#page/11/mode/1up) mostly coincided with #4 (IV) from the LSJ entry above.

Is this a manuscript discrepancy, or might there be another explanation for the use of 'eagle' in this context? Or is 'vulture' a better translation?

*Please keep answers restricted to the translation of the word ἀετοί itself as [there is already another question concerning the meaning of the surrounding context.](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/13/423)*

Comment: It might not help much, but you might as well add [the LSJ entry](http://www.tlg.uci.edu/lsj/#eid=1874&context=lsj&action=from-search) to your resources; also the [Moulton and Milligan entry](https://archive.org/stream/vocabularyofgree00mouluoft#page/11/mode/1up), which is limited on ἀετός, but one would want to check.

Comment: + have a look at Hagner, *[Matthew 14-28](http://www.amazon.com/dp/084991096X/)*, p. 707: "Whether οἱ ἀετοί refers to 'egales' or 'vultures' does not matter (the two were often classed together), but a reference to the Romans does not make sense here, as it might have in the preceding pericope; nor does the carrion symbolize anything in particular. As tempting as it appears to many commentators, the proverb need not be allegorized." There is further discussion in context. FWIW!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "eagles" is correct and means "eagles". The problem is not in the translation which is "eagles", but with the modern interpretation of why Jesus said:
Matthew 24:28

> For wherever the carcass is, there will the eagles be gathered together.

Jesus was referring to the Roman Empire (eagles) having its emblem on their flag the eagle (as does our American flag have the eagle on the top of the flagpole). Jesus was prophesying that the Romans will come and gather around the Spiritually Dead Israel and destroy it as they did in 70AD.

Luke 21:21-22

> <sup>**21**</sup> Then let them which are in Judaea flee to the mountains; and let them which are in the middle of it depart out; and let not them that are in the countries enter thereinto. <sup>**22**</sup> For these be the days of vengeance, that all things which are written may be fulfilled.

Matthew 24 and Luke 21 describe the destruction of Jerusalem.

Matthew 24:34

> Truly I say to you, This generation shall not pass, till all these things be fulfilled.

An eagle is not a vulture.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: This is essentially the conclusion I’ve also come to in the intervening years since I posed this question, so I’ve marked this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Not as Clear-cut a Distinction as Modern Science

Note that even in modern taxonomy, eagles and many vultures are related, both being in the [Accipitridae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accipitridae) family for taxonomic purposes, of which that article notes:

> Many well-known birds, such as hawks, eagles, kites, harriers and Old
>   World vultures are included in this group.

Specifically the "[Old World Vultures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_World_vulture)" is meaning those that would be referred to in the Middle-east (the New World referring to the America's).

While [eagles are birds of prey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle), at least some (Perhaps most or all? I'm not sure of that. This page on [accipitridae](http://www.raptorresearchfoundation.org/education/raptor-world#4) notes that a large number of the kites from that family group scavenge, and [this entry specifically mentions under "Food Habits"](http://eol.org/pages/8016/details#data_object_18630281) that carrion scavenging is common of the group) are as the [Golden Eagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Eagle), where it is noted, "Golden eagles are not above scavenging for carrion." This is of course the main aspect of vultures, for "[Both Old World and New World vultures are scavenging birds, feeding mostly from carcasses of dead animals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_World_vulture)."

### Conclusion

There is not a need to be too concerned about a clear-cut distinction in the use of the word in Scripture. The word ἀετός is simply a reference in some passages to birds that are gathering to feast on dead bodies, of which both vultures and (at least some) eagles are characterized to do. The fact that the Bible indicates such is occurring in those passages means that even if they fall under the classification of modern day "eagle," they are of the type that *does* eat carrion as well, like vultures.

Probably the leaning toward "vulture" today in translations is because in our modern classifications, that type of bird better pictures one that gathers to eat dead things, whereas many people think of a "bird of prey" (a hunter) when they hear "eagle."

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me is the distinct difference in what comes to mind when one says "vulture" vs "eagle" and what the two mean as far as scripture goes for a Believer. However, one would have to study to understand that a vulture is also classified in the eagle family. Similarly, Cain and Able were classified as the same species, however something extremely different was apparently going on in the inside. Therefore, a person would have to definitely be a student of the WORD and scripture to interpret God's  intended meaning.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/42723)

Answer (score 0):

Below I have pasted what I believe to be the most convincing argument about this passage:

> The Greek word used here in Matthew 24 is also used in the parallel
> passage in Luke 17:37.  The only other uses for this word are
> Revelations 4:7, 8:13, and 12:14.  The context of each of these
> passages clearly refers to a heavenly creature doing God’s will.
>
> Their reasoning is connected to the Greek word for  “body.” [Strong’s # 4430] It is based on two words which mean a “body” and an adjective meaning “fallen.”  So, it is sometimes translated as
> “corpse.”
>
> Now, an eagle is a predator that only goes after live prey.
>
> Vultures, or buzzards, are scavengers that feed on carcasses, the
> deader the better.   So, some translators substitute vultures even
> though the Greek uses “eagles” since they reason that it fits better
> with a “fallen body.”
>
> I contend that the Catholic translation that is found in older Bibles
> which used the word “eagle” is better and that this passage refers to
> the Sacrifice of the Mass around which God the Father would gather His
> children till the end of time.
>
> Although, the Greek word for Body refers to a fallen body – for
> example, this same Greek word is used to refer to Christ’s Body when
> it is taken down from the cross in Mark 15:45 – I believe that it is a
> reference to eternal sacrifice of the Mass where Jesus is perpetually
> offered to God the Father both in Heaven and re-presented here on
> earth at the Sacrifice of the Mass.  1 Corinthians 11:26  “For as
> often as you eat this bread and drink the cup, you proclaim the death
> of the Lord until he comes.”
>
> Consider:
> Revelation 5:6
>
> > And between the throne and the four living creatures
> > and among the elders, I saw a Lamb standing, as though it had been
> > slain …”
>
> The Lamb, a symbol for Jesus who is our Paschal Lamb, is standing.
> Standing is the posture of the officiating Old Testament priest.  And
> this Lamb appears as though He has been slain.  Christ is both the
> Eternal High Priest and the Victim.  So, this imagery fits perfectly
> with our understanding of Jesus offering Himself to God the Father
> once for all time, eternally in Heaven.
>
> Hebrews 7:24-25
>
> > but he [Jesus] holds his priesthood permanently,
> > because he continues for ever.  Consequently he is able for all time
> > to save those who draw near to God through him, since he always lives
> > to make intercession for them.
>
> And Hebrews chapter 10 goes on to warn those who knowingly sin and
> deliberately refuse to avail themselves of the graces offered by the
> Sacrifice of the Mass no longer have any sacrifice that expiates their
> sins since there is no other Savior except Jesus.
>
> A Weak Theology
>
> Some lay “Catholic” educators have ignored and in some cases even
> denied the sacrificial nature of the Mass and contended that it is
> only a communal meal.  The Holy Father John Paul II has corrected this
> misunderstanding in his encyclical letter Ecclesia De Eucharistia
> (2003 AD),
>
> > “10. …  Unfortunately, alongside these lights, there are also shadows. … At times one encounters an extremely reductive
> > understanding of the Eucharistic mystery. Stripped of its sacrificial
> > meaning, it is celebrated as if it were simply a fraternal banquet.”
>
> Perhaps the difficulty in recognizing the association between the
> “fallen body” in Matthew 24:28 with our Paschal Lamb, “standing as
> though slain,” has been due to these shadows and bad theology that
> Pope John Paul II speaks about.
>
> Matthew 24:23-28 - the Context
>
> In Matthew chapter 24 Jesus tells us not to be alarmed by false
> declarations that the second coming has occurred and that He is either
> here or there.  After saying where He is not it is natural that He
> would then say where He will be.
>
> Verses 27-28 record Jesus’s conclusion,  “For as the lightning come
> forth from the east and shines even to the west, so also will the
> coming of the Son of Man be.  Wherever the body is, there will the
> eagles be gathered together.”
>
> In the parallel passage in Luke 17:20-37  Jesus also tells of His
> second coming.  He tells of how “one” will be taken and one will be
> left.  His disciples asked Him, “Where, Lord?” And in verse 37 Jesus
> replies, “Wherever the body is, there will the eagles be gathered
> together.”
>
> The word used for “body” in the above verse is the same Greek word
> used in the institution of the Eucharist when Jesus said, “This is my
> Body.”
>
> It is also interesting to note that the Greek does not state that the
> eagles will gather, rather it says that the eagles will be gathered.
> Perhaps this is allusion to  John 6:44  “No one can come to me unless
> the Father who sent me draw him, and I will raise him on the last
> day.”
>
> It is God the Father who moves people’s hearts with the gift of faith
> to accept what Jesus promises in John 6.  So, it is God the Father who
> is doing the gathering of the eagles by blessing them with the gift of
> faith.
>
> Traditionally the Saints are said to have the eagle eye, that is, the
> eye of faith.
>
> John 6:53-56
>
> > So Jesus said to them,  ‘Truly, truly, I say to you,
> > unless you eat the flesh of the Son of man and drink his blood, you
> > have no life in you; he who eats my flesh and drinks my blood has
> > eternal life, and I will raise him up at the last day.  For my flesh
> > is food indeed, and my blood is drink indeed.  He who eats my flesh
> > and drinks my blood abides in me, and I in him.’ ”
>
> So, for these reasons I believe Matthew 24:28 should be translated as
> follows, “Wherever the body is, there the eagles will be gathered
> together.”

This information was found here: https://www.defendingthebride.com/sc/mass/mat24.html