# Interpretation of Psalm 110:1 in Consideration of the New Testament

Tags: second-coming

Psalm 110:1 (NKJV)

> The LORD said to my Lord, “Sit at My right hand, Till I make Your enemies Your footstool.

Could this be interpreted to mean The LORD [YHWH, Yahweh (H3068), God the Father) is telling King David's Lord [Adon (H113), Adonay (H136), God the Son] to wait until He (Yahweh) kills the wicked of the earth and has their bodies taken to "winepress of the wrath of God" (Rev 14:19). And that these bodies will be the Son of Man's (Adonay) footstool when "He will sit on the throne of His glory" (Mt 25:31) to judge the surviving Armageddon sheep/goats?

Scripture considerations:

> For where the carcass is, there the eagles will be gathered together. (Mt 24:28)

Observation: This event occurs before the Son of Man returns to earth (Mt 24:30, 31).

> “where Lord?” ...”Wherever the body is, there the eagles will be gathered together.” (Lk 17:37)

> Thus says the LORD of hosts: "... <sup>**19**</sup> Behold, a whirlwind of the LORD has gone forth in fury- A violent whirlwind! It will fall on the head of the wicked. <sup>**20**</sup> … **In the latter days you will understand it perfectly.**" (Jer 23:16)

> <sup>**32**</sup>Thus says the LORD of hosts: “Behold, disaster shall go forth From nation to nation, And a great whirlwind shall be raised up From the farthest parts of the earth. <sup>**33**</sup> “And at that day the slain of the LORD shall be from one end of the earth even to the other end of the earth. They shall not be lamented, or gathered, or buried; they shall be refuse on the ground. (Jer 25:32, 33)

> <sup>**18**</sup> Thus says the LORD: " … <sup>**23**</sup> Behold, the whirlwind of the LORD Goes forth with fury, a continuing whirlwind; it will fall violently on the head of the wicked. … <sup>**24**</sup> … **In the latter days you will consider it**.” (Jer 30:18, 23, 24)

Comment: Up-voted +1. See also Hebrews 1:5 to 14.

Comment: Consider also a little bit different hierarchy: god father - ύψιστος - “highest” (lord) and two or more lords under him, maybe both/all also being his sons (because in the same psalm 110:3 one is said to be born before the other - Christos before Lucifer?) I leave it open to who the handle YHWH should be assigned to.

Comment: Voted to close because this question is not about the meaning of the text, it is about how to interpret the text in a specifically Christian context.

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahimalYahud. Why not answer the question instead of voting to close it. I think you know know who the "LORD" and my "lord" is in this question. I am interested about your understanding of the verse in question.

Comment: The aramaic translation interpret this verse as like: The LORD said to me (David) about my Lord (Saul), “Sit(wait) to My right hand, Till I make Your enemies Your footstool.

Comment: In the OT, the term "The LORD" always refers to the tribal-national supreme deity of Israel and Judaism; i.e., YaHVeH-Jehovah (e.g., GEN 2:4; EXO 6:3 KJV).  Also, the term "my Lord" becomes less confusing when the uppercase "L" is replaced with a lowercase "l" (cp. RSV at PSA 110:1). In this way, the term "my lord" can be correctly read and understood similar to the way the British address a person of titled nobility; e.g., a Duke or an Earl, or their king.

Comment: @hank. Connecting this verse with the NT, we find in Acts 2:32-36 it was Jesus who was crucified and made lord.. If the 2nd lord is adonay as you contend, how is it possible to crucify Adonay,? Who is the God that made Adonay lord?

Answer (score 2):

The OP asked: "Could this be interpreted to mean The LORD... is telling King David's Lord [... God the Son] to wait until He (Yahweh) kills the wicked of the earth..." (Rev 14:19)

Asked in this way (*could*), the answer can be nothing other than "Yes." The real question is *should* it be interpreted in the way suggested. To this, I would answer "no."

The argument hinges on the identity of the person called "my lord," who is addressed by the LORD. One need not be an anti-trinitarian to recognize that this is not God the son, but King David whose praises are being sung by the psalmist. The Catholic authorities who edited the online version of [NABRE](https://bible.usccb.org/bible/psalms/110) - strong Trinitarians themselves - interpret "The LORD says to my lord" as

> A polite form of address of an inferior to a superior, cf. 1 Sm 25:25;
> 2 Sm 1:10. The court singer refers to the king.

In other words, God speaks to King David, whom the singer calls "my lord." It may be objected that David is the author of the psalm and it does not make sense that he would speak of himself as "my lord." However, [Jewish commentators](https://jewsforjudaism.org/knowledge/articles/psalm-110-a-jewish-perspective) as well as modern critics point out that:

> *L’David* literally means “to David” or concerning him, it does not simply mean “composed by David.”

As for the suggestion concerning the psalm's relation to the Book of Revelation, I think a simpler answer is better: the psalm refers to God inviting God's beloved David to sit at his right hand as God's co-regent, while God works to make their enemies an integral part of David's kingdom. Readers of Revelation may interpret the OP verse as related to Revelation but the text itself has a more practical meaning: King David enjoyed God's full support as he rose to power and subdued his enemies.

**Readers are, of course, free to interpret the verse as they please. However, it requires a thick filter to interpret it as suggested in the OP. The more likely meaning is that it sings of God speaking to King David, whom the singer calls "my lord."**

Comment: Dan - Doesn't King David resurrect (does not ascend) with Daniel "at the end of days" (Dan 12:13)? I believe that the Lord of King David means the resurrected/ascended Messiah (Christ Jesus).

Comment: I understand that many Christians understand it that way. But the author was a Jew. I prefer to read it as I think it was originally intended but its human author even though I  think Jesus was indeed the messiah.

Comment: Dan - Son of David, Messiah yes but do you think He was the Son of God? (Luke 22:70 Then they all said, "are You then the Son of God?" So He said to them, "You rightly say that I am."

Answer (score 2):

The key to understanding this passage in Ps 110:1 is Heb 10:12, 13 which says:

> But when this Priest had offered for all time one sacrifice for sins,
> He sat down at the right hand of God. Since that time, He waits for
> His enemies to be made a footstool for His feet

Thus, the event prophesied in Ps 110:1 is still future, to reach final fulfilment as predicted by Rev 11:15 -

> Then the seventh angel sounded his trumpet, and loud voices called out
> in heaven: “The kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of our
> Lord and of His Christ, and He will reign forever and ever.”

Thus, while Christ gained complete victory over sin by making full and complete atonement for sin at the cross, it will only be at the conclusion of the great final judgement that all (including the wicked) will acknowledge Jesus as Lord (Phil 2:9-11), and thus, make the wicked a footstool for His feet; ie, have complete victory over the wicked.

**APPENDIX - Literal or symbolic?**

There is quite a degree of metaphoric/symbolic language in this idea of the enemies of God/Christ being a "footstool" as observed in the following references:

- Isa 66:1 - This is what the LORD says: “Heaven is my throne, and the earth is my footstool. Where is the house you will build for me? Where will my resting place be?
- Acts 7:49 - “’Heaven is my throne, and the earth is my footstool. What kind of house will you build for me? says the Lord. Or where will my resting place be?
- 1 Chron 28:2 - King David rose to his feet and said: “Listen to me, my fellow Israelites, my people. I had it in my heart to build a house as a place of rest for the ark of the covenant of the LORD, for the footstool of our God, and I made plans to build it.

Comment: This Psalm existed a long time before Hebrew 10. What did this Psalm mean originally, before the Christian era? Or are you suggesting that it in fact had no meaning at all until the Christian era? How does this post answer the OP questions?

Comment: @AbuMunirIbnIbrahimalYahud - I am effectively suggesting that it is a messianic psalm.

Comment: Dottard - I take issue with your interpretation "thus, make the wicked a footstool for His feet." I am writing about dead bodies (of the wicked) spoken of by Jesus "For where the carcass is, there the eagles will be gathered together. (Mt 24:28) before He comes to earth as the Son of Man (Mt 24:30).

Comment: @hank - I think that should be the subject of its own question.  However, suffice to say here that we are talking about two different metaphors.

Comment: Dottard - How about - What did Jesus mean when He said "For where the carcass is, there the eagles will be gathered together." (Mt 24:28)?

Comment: @hank - That would be a great question on its own.  It has been much debated from apostolic times with numerous opinions expressed.

Answer (score 1):

The account in Mark 12:36 is a reference to Psalm 110:1. Examining Psalm 110:1 we find,

The OP keeps insisting that the 2nd lord in psalm 110:1 is Adonay but it is not. Here is the what bible hub shows it.

**to my Lord:
לַֽאדֹנִ֗י (la·ḏō·nî)**
Preposition-l | Noun - masculine singular construct | first person common singular
Strong's 113: Sovereign, controller

**My Lord.**--**Heb.**, **adoni**, an address of honour to those more noble than the speaker, or superior in rank: to a father, Genesis 31:35; to a brother, Numbers 12:11; a royal consort, 1Kings 1:17-18; to a prince, 1Kings 3:17; with the addition of the royal title, "my Lord, O king," 2Samuel 14:19

There is only one Adonay YHWH.

LORD” or “the LORD” in the OT represents (YHWH) God. This is not to be confused with the Greek word Kurios, which is used of Jesus and is a title of respect, honor and authority. The title “Lord” is used of many people in the Bible not just God and Jesus. God made Jesus both lord and Christ. Nobody makes God lord. Jesus as the Son of God, yes. But, God the Son, no. There is no God the son in the bible. –

The 1st LORD in Psalm 110:1 is Jehovah/YHWH. The second lord is translated from the hebrew word adoni. The word adoni is a title which never refers to God. It does not mean God the son. Peter narrated God's plan based on the truth of Psalm 110:1 in Acts 2:33-36 Being therefore by the right hand of God exalted and having received of the Father the promise of the Holy Spirit, he hath poured forth this, which ye see and hear. For David ascended not into the heavens: but he saith himself, The Lord said unto my Lord, Sit thou on my right hand, Till I make thine enemies the footstool of thy feet. Let all the house of Israel therefore know assuredly, that **God hath made him** both Lord and Christ, this Jesus whom ye crucified.

The God of Jesus made him both Lord and Christ.

Mark 12:36 ASV

> David himself said in the Holy Spirit, The Lord said unto my Lord, Sit thou on my right hand, Till I make thine enemies the footstool of thy feet

Psalm 110:1 ASV

> A Psalm of David. Jehovah saith unto my Lord, Sit thou at my right hand, Until I make thine enemies thy footstool.

This could not be interpreted to mean "The LORD [YHWH, Yahweh (H3068), God the Father) is telling King David's Lord [Adon (H113), Adhonay (H136), God the Son"because ***adoni is not the same as Adonay*** and that **there is no God the Son"** in the bible.

Peter already identified who the second lord of Psalm 110:1 is and it is Jesus whom he says was crucified. This further proves that the second lord of Psalm 110:1 is adoni because crucifying Adonay is not possible.

Comment: Alex - My reference (The Complete WordStudy Old Testament KJV) has Lord as Adhon H113. As far as God the Son, I contend that Lord (Adhonay H136) of 110:5 as well as    Is 7:14 use of Lord (Adhonay H136) means God the Son.

Comment: @hank. The word Lord: לַֽאדֹנִ֗י (la·ḏō·nî) does not mean YHWH or God. It is never used as a title applied to YHWH.

Comment: Alex - I agree Lord does not mean YHWH. Levan wrote "In this psalm, they are two in the sense of Persons, but one in the sense of sharing one throne and authority." And I content that the second person is Adhonay (H136)

Comment: @hank. You can contend that the second person is adonay, but that doesn't not change the fact that it is adoni, a human superior. Even Bible hub shows it to be adonii not adonhay.

Comment: Alex - Then what is your interpretation of Is 7:14 Therefore the Lord (Adhonay, H136) himself shall give you a sign (oth, H 236)?

Comment: @hank. Please post that as a question. I will try to answer it when I can.

Comment: Alex - Does Isaiah 7:13a, ... "Hear now, O house of David! ... 14a ...The Lord Himself will give you a sign: ... " mean Adonay (H136, Lord) Himself will give the house of David a miracle (ot, H226) in the future (~680 yrs)?

Comment: @hank. The Lord in Isaiah 7:14 is Adonay. This is the same first LORD in Psalm 110 :1. Where are you trying to lead me with your comments? Question like this one in your comment, you can find in bible hub?

Comment: Alex - As I read Pslam 110:1, The first LORD is Yahweh H3068 the second Lord is Adonay H136 (verse 5) the same as in Isaiah 7:14.

Comment: @hank. You and I can say what we want to. But it really is that there is only 1 Adonay. Why don't you post it as a question so we don't have to go back and forth in the comments section. Either you or I is not being truthful. Here is how bible hub shows it. It is adoni not Adonay. to my Lord:
לַֽאדֹנִ֗י (la·ḏō·nî)
Preposition-l | Noun - masculine singular construct | first person common singular
Strong's 113: Sovereign, controller.

Comment: Agreed. One last thought - The riddle posed by Jesus in the Matt 22:43-45; Mark 12:36-37; Luke 20:42-44, "If David then calls Him 'Lord,' how is He his son" which the Pharisees could not answer. They were not expecting Jesus as the Son of God (Luke 22:70) to be the "Lord".

Comment: @hank. One last thought  “LORD” or “the LORD” in the OT  represents (YHWH) God. This is not to be confused with the Greek word Kurios, which is used of Jesus and is a title of respect, honor and authority. The title “Lord” is used of many people in the Bible not just God and Jesus. God made Jesus both lord and Christ. Nobody makes God lord. Jesus as the Son of God, yes. But, God the Son, no. There is no God the son in the bible.

Comment: Alex - I agree there is not "God the Son" in the bible. However, John 3:16 ... "He gave His only begotten Son" ... . Acts 13:33 ... "He has raised up Jesus. As it is also written in the second psalm: 'You are My Son, Today I have begotten You.' 34 And He raised him from the dead" ... .

Comment: Alex - Regarding Kurios: 1 Th 4:16 For the Lord (Kurios, G2962) Himself will descend from heaven with a shout, with a voice of an archangel, and with the trumpet of God. And the dead in Christ will rise first."

Comment: @hank. Jesus being called Lord does not make him God the Son. That is why there is no record of him being worshipped as God from Genesis to Revelation. If he was God from the beginning, he would have been the God that the prophets, apostles and disciples worship.

Comment: I agree. But the Lord who comes to earth to resurrect believers does, IMHO. Additional  scripture that Jesus was"the Son of God" (aka "God the Son"):

Comment: Alex - 1. Mk 14:6 ..."Are You the Christ, the Son of God?' 62 Jesus said "I AM." 2. Lk 22:67 " If You are the Christ , tell us." ... 69 Hereafter the Son of Man will sit on the right hand of the power of God." 70 Then they all said, "Are You the Son of God?" So He said to them , "You rightly say that I am." 3. Jn 1:1 ...the Word was God. 2 He was in the beginning with God. 34 ... this is the "Son of God." 4. 8:38 ... "... before Abraham was, I AM."

Comment: Oh boy!! Hank, bless him, is getting into a whole new *aspect* with that last comment. He either doesn't want to understand the truth of the matter, or is just honestly befuddled. Either way you can't just go on and on with this in the comments section, as you have already pointed out. Let me relieve your *frustration*, if I may call it that - the anonymous and therefore cowardly downvotes must wear on you too -  with another upvote.

Comment: Olde English - regarding "He either doesn't want to understand the truth of the matter, or is just honestly befuddled. " What is your Truth? ... And please explain exactly how I am "befuddled." (use scripture to support your argument)

Comment: @hank - If you can't follow Alex then you are not going to be able to follow me, so I pass.

Comment: @Hank - It just so happens that I have already written about **Matt,24:28** and **Luke 17:37**, not to mention **Matt, 24:40-41**. You can see my answer here:- https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13/meaning-of-where-there-is-a-dead-body-there-the-vultures-will-gather/81450#81450

Comment: Olde English - I see there was no mention of: 

    For where the carcass is, there the eagles will be gathered together. (Mt 24:28)

Observation: This event occurs before the Son of Man returns to earth (Mt 24:30, 31).  ..... And what is your "truth of the matter?"

Comment: @hank - Ok. First of all, I think we have a dual prophecy scenario here; 70 AD firstly and then the *future* Armageddon, at which point we will have the *coming of the Son of Man.* I also think both Matthew & Luke are talking about the same *battlefield(s)* (Jerusalem and then the World). One should not think "Rapture" here; "taken" = destroyed; "left" = saved. In Luke it's easier to fathom, being broader in scope. *Where Lord?"* is responded to immediately via Jesus with: *"Where the body is ... vultures be gathered."* Whereas when Matt' uses "corpse"(carcass), and Luke uses "body" ... tbc ..

Comment: @hank - ... vultures will pick at both, but that's not the eagles thing, so that's probably why *vultures* is the correct translation. Now I don't want to start an endless back and forth here. I've given you what I believe, without going into too much detail, so let's leave it at this. There are too many comments here as it is and I don't want to have to go to "chat".

Comment: Olde English - I agree, both Matthew and Luke are talking about Armageddon but also about the "winepress of the wrath of God" (Rev 14:19). Definition: suma,G4983 (II)(B) ... a dead body of a beast, meaning a carcass (Luke 17:37 [cf. Matt 24:28 where the word ptoma G(4430), corpse is used]). But please keep in mind, Matt 24:28 occurs before the Son of Man coming to earth (Matt 24:29, 30).

Comment: Alex - Does the crowning of 2nd temple high priest Joshua (Zech 6:11-13) mean the future Davidic Messiah will be both priest and king?

Comment: 1. Zech 6:11-13 Take the silver and gold, make an elaborate crown, and set it on the head of Joshua the son of JehoZadak, the high priest. 12 Then speak to him, saying, 'Thus says the LORD of hosts, saying: "Behold, the Man whose name is the BRANCH! ... 13 ... And shall sit and rule on His throne; So He shall be a priest on His 
throne, ... ."'
2. Psalm 110:4 The LORD has sworn And will not relent, "You are a priest forever According to the order of MelchiZedek."

Answer (score 1):

The purpose for why the Lord adduces this psalm is to rise the intellect of Jews in their expectation of the Messiah. It is taken for granted that one of the Lords in David's Psalms, namely "my Lord", denotes Messiah and another - God the Father.

If so, then who this Messiah, the addressee of the Psalm, can be? Jews think he will be a son, that is to say, a descendant of David in just a human, genetical (although this term is anachronistic) way, and only that. But the Lord wants them to understand that the Person or Hypostasis of the Messiah was alive already then when David said those words about Him. Thus, David addressed the Person of the Messiah as "my Lord".

Now, can this "my Lord" be a man? No, because no man lives before a historical birth. Angel? - Impossible, for angels do not sit on throne, as does this "my Lord", who is asked to sit on the throne. Now, who can be higher than all angels and all men, being neither of the two, and sitting on throne? Only God whom men should worship. In this psalm, they are two in the sense of Persons, but one in the sense of sharing one throne and authority.

Comment: Lenvan - I agree

Comment: @hank Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

> Could this be interpreted to mean The LORD [YHWH, Yahweh (H3068), God the Father) is telling King David's Lord [Adon (H113), Adonay (H136), God the Son] to wait until He (Yahweh) kills the wicked of the earth and has their bodies taken to "winepress of the wrath of God" (Rev 14:19). And that these bodies will be the Son of Man's (Adonay) footstool when "He will sit on the throne of His glory" (Mt 25:31) to judge the surviving Armageddon sheep/goats?

No, I don't think that's the case. Rather, the reference to "footstool" in Psalm 110:1 is, I believe, a reference to the temple.

See the following:

1 Chronicles 28:2 [ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Chronicles%2028%3A2&version=ESV),

> Then King David rose to his feet and said: “Hear me, my brothers and my people. I had it in my heart to build a house of rest for the ark of the covenant of the Lord and for the footstool of our God, and I made preparations for building.

Psalm 99:5 [ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2099%3A5&version=ESV),

> Exalt the Lord our God; worship at his footstool! Holy is he!

Psalm 132:7 [ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%20132%3A7&version=ESV),

> “Let us go to his dwelling place; let us worship at his footstool!”

Isaiah 66:1 [ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2066%3A1&version=ESV),

> Thus says the Lord: “Heaven is my throne, and the earth is my footstool; what is the house that you would build for me, and what is the place of my rest?

Lamentations 2:1 [ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Lamentations%202%3A1&version=ESV),

> How the Lord in his anger has set the daughter of Zion under a cloud! He has cast down from heaven to earth the splendor of Israel;
> he has not remembered his footstool in the day of his anger.

In each of the five instances listed above, there is ample proof that "footstool" is a metaphor for the temple, that is, the House of YHWH.

The question then assumes, from Psalm 110:1 that since the enemies are to be turned into a footstool, it conjures the image of a conqueror with his foot on the neck of the subdued.

But consider, in light of the Messianic nature of the prophecy, and how it was interpreted to apply to Jesus of Nazareth, that within a Christian context, Jesus came to save (i.e. not conquer) His enemies.

For example, Jesus taught His students to "[love [their] enemies](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%205%3A44&version=ESV)".

Paul, quoting from [Proverbs 25:20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Proverbs%2025%3A21&version=ESV), writes that if an enemy hungers, the Christian disciple should feed him/her. If the enemy thirsts, the Christian disciple should give that enemy something to drink ([Romans 12:20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%2012%3A20&version=ESV)).

Earlier in Romans, Paul writes of how Christ died for His enemies, in order to save them from the wrath of God:

Romans 5:6-11 [ESv](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%205%3A6-11&version=ESV),

> <sup>**6**</sup> For while we were still weak, at the right time Christ died for the ungodly. <sup>**7**</sup> For one will scarcely die for a righteous person—though perhaps for a good person one would dare even to die— <sup>**8**</sup> but God shows his love for us in that while we were still sinners, Christ died for us. <sup>**9**</sup> Since, therefore, we have now been justified by his blood, much more shall we be saved by him from the wrath of God. <sup>**10**</sup> For if while we were enemies we were reconciled to God by the death of his Son, much more, now that we are reconciled, shall we be saved by his life. <sup>**11**</sup> More than that, we also rejoice in God through our Lord Jesus Christ, through whom we have now received reconciliation.

Jesus didn't come to destroy, but to save ([John 3:16-17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203%3A16-17&version=ESV)).

Indeed, the whole mission and purpose of the Messiah, from both an Old Covenant, prophetic context, and a New Covenant, fulfillment context, the overwhelming evidence is that Jesus was sent by His Father YHWH to redeem and save, reconcile, forgive, purge of sin, justify, and sanctify people who had been alienated from God, and in their alienation, had become His enemies.

This then lends to the idea that YHWH sent David's Lord, that is, the Messiah, Jesus, to peacefully and lovingly subdue, as it were, His enemies, by taking their place and paying the ultimate price for them, [a substitutionary death on a cross](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20corinthians%205%3A21&version=ESV) under the judgment and wrath of God.

So, when I read Psalm 110:1, and I see the reference to the Messiah's footstool, I think of what God and His Son accomplished to save sinners and turn them into [recipients of the Holy Spirit](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts%202%3A4&version=ESV), whereby they are made a temple, that is, a footstool unto YHWH and King David's Lord (See, e.g. [1 Corinthians 3:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%203%3A16&version=ESV), [1 Corinthians 6:19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%206%3A19&version=ESV), [2 Corinthians 6:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Corinthians%206%3A16&version=ESV), and [Ephesians 2:21](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%202%3A21&version=ESV)).

Comment: agarza - Good points for consideration.

Answer (score -1):

1. There is no reason to discredit the authorship of Psalm 110 **to** David. [authorship of Psalm 110](https://archive.org/download/psalm-110-search/Psalm%20110%20Search.pdf)

What was the initial position of "lord" of the verse 1 of Psalm 110? It cannot be behind יְהוָ֙ה as this is pejorative against the dignity of God as per  2 Sam. 2:21 עַל־יְמִֽינְךָ֙  So it is certain that this "Lord" was on the left!

> "... They make me repay what I did **not steal**!" (Ps. 69:4 NET)

So this Lord of verse five as a fleshly descendant of David is at his right hand, but will be in the future at the right hand of God as made the only Lord.

> Men and brethren, let me freely speak unto you of the **patriarch David**, that he is both dead and buried, and his sepulchre is with us unto this day. Therefore being a prophet, and knowing that God had sworn with an oath to him, **that of the fruit of his loins, according to the flesh**, he would raise up Christ to sit on his throne; (Acts 2:29-30 KJV)

2. Mary's lineage came from Nathan, David's son by Bathsheba. Therefore **Jesus was descended from David**  through Nathan and legally through Solomon to exercise the Priesthood after the order of Melchizedek

> "So then, **exalted to the right hand of God**... " Acts 2:33 NET

> "τη the δεξια  right ουν  therefore του of the θεου God  υψωθεις  was set on high.."  Acts 2:33 NET

The Author of Acts of Apostles indicates in this verse the literal fulfillment of the prophecy of Psalms 110.1

> Which he wrought in Christ (Priesthood and Kingship/Elohim), when he raised him from the dead (to the **left**), and set him at his own **right** hand in the heavenly places (enthroned),  Ephesians 1:20 KJV

The Lordship quality of the first verse of Psalm 110 was explained by Jesus: "...David in the spirit..." (Matthew 22:43 KJV). Already in verse 5, David is no longer in the Spirit, and therefore only sees him as his fleshly descendant, from which he would come out of his loins, therefore, he is "at his right hand".

Comment: This is a very long, rambling, hard to follow post. I suggest that you edit it to one-quarter of its length and re-organize it for readability. It is not clear what your point is currently.

Comment: This verse to me is as complex as John 5:39. What bothers me is the fact that I don't know who the author is, what I'm researching now.

Comment: Roberto - FYI, The Complete WordStudy Old Testament, KJV, ISBN 0-89937-665-6, 1994, AMG International, page 1531, Psalm 110-5 has Lord as Adhonay (H136).

Comment: I have this book, it's far away now, in the rural outback. When I can I will see this quote.

Comment: Roberto - Roger that.

Comment: @RobertoPezzinFilho the Ps 110:5 from the NWT that you have is a bit dated. See the current translation at https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/psalms/110/

Comment: Roberto - Thanks for the up check but where is the Hebrew names for the Lord, namely Adon H113 and Adhonay H136?

Comment: Roberto - Is 7:14 Therefore the Lord (Adhonay, H136) himself shall give you a sign (oth, H 236). Therefore, I disagree with your use of "naturally."

Comment: You are right! I have difficulty with English. I meant a natural ancestry through Mary.

Comment: Roberto - Roger that.

Comment: The riddle posed by Jesus in the gospels (Matt 22:43-45; Mark 12:36-37; Luke 20:42-44), "If David then calls Him 'Lord,' how is He his son" which the Pharisees could not answer. They were not expecting Jesus as the Son of God (Luke 22:70) to be the "Lord".

Comment: When I read Psalm 82:1, I understand that the Jewish religious caste considered themselves gods by tradition inherited from Moses and Aaron (Elohim) and did not consider Jesus because he did not learn the letters (John 7:15), teaching that already existed from the Abram's time. Indeed, being Elohim and Adonai was too much for the Jews' minds...

Comment: Roberto - I agree

Comment: Roberto - About your comment "did not consider Jesus because he did not learn the letters (John 7:15)". "How does this Man know letters, having never studied" to me means He knew the written word without being taught by man.

Comment: You are correct in the argument.

Comment: Roberto - Do you think that Adonai, H???? and Elohim H430, have the same meaning as Godhead G2305, Theiotes Rm 1:20 "For since the creation of the world His invisible attributes are clearly seen, being understood by the things that are made, even His eternal power and Godhead, ... "?

Comment: I am going to check this but, as far as I know, it remains in the proposals